# Cordova Url Loading Not Working

Tags: android, ios, cordova, visual-studio-cordova

I am coding a Cordova application in Visual Studio. It is a hosted web app which means Cordova starts a webview with the local index.html and after deviceready, I redirect the document location to my locally hosted web url.

When I was testing on iPhone (iOS 9.3), I noticed that the Cordova app hangs/freezes at the splash screen after I rebuild the hosted web page. I thought it might be due to the latency occurring after compilation because it works in the successive trials. And I tried to debug using Visual Studio, attaching to the local device, and using the console I changed the url to test several sites. When response is immediate, no problem but when there is even about a second of latency, it does not navigate, but there seems no error in the Javascript Console of the Visual Studio debugger.

I know that there is a "loadUrlTimeout" parameter in the config.xml for Android but there is none for iOS. (I did not try it with Android if there is such a problem there too.) Am I doing something wrong? Is this the expected behavior? How can I fix it?

Comment: Does this problem exist when you open your application with web browser?